# Word for people who are led by a leader

Tags: single-word-requests

Just like the pairs Interviewer & Interviewee or Employer & Employee, is there any word for leader?

Say the word is *x*. I'm trying to construct a statement where I have to say that, "A leader needs to be both gregarious and exemplary to inspire the *x*".

The sentence could possibly be rephrased to avoid the word that I'm looking for. But I want to know if such a word exists.

Comment: Depends on what sense you wish to convey.  "Follower" is only slightly pejorative (check its synonyms), "sheep" much more.  "Leadee" is occasionally used in a jocular sense.

Comment: word **adherents** should work.

Comment: I'm with @HotLicks. And "follower" need not be pejorative at all.

Comment: Unfortunately Stack Exchange have, in their wisdom, made the detailed help for this tag far more difficult to find. [I'll see if it's possible to do something about that.] We need more information than just the sample sentence: [have a look at the help](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/single-word-requests/info).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the word you are looking for is 'the led'.

> A leader needs to be both gregarious and exemplary to inspire the **led**.

See also :

> Leaders and Led

[Daily People](http://www.slp.org/pdf/de_leon/eds1912/jan02_1912.pdf)

> Relationships - The Leaders and the Led

[YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oK7-sqNkJUw)

> Why great leaders love to be led

[The Riverstone Group](http://www.theriverstonegroup.com/why-great-leaders-love-to-be-led/)

Comment: Using led in this sense is not too common. But it's not too uncommon either I guess..

Answer (score 2):

You have **leaders** and you have [**followers**](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/followers):

> [Merriam-Webster]
>
> **1 a** : one in the service of another : retainer
>   **b** : one that follows the opinions or teachings of another
>   **c** : one that imitates another
>
> The party drew most of its *followers* from among young people.
>   The band has a large group of *followers*.
>   He had a reputation of being a *follower*, not a leader.

In your sentence, however, you would need to say "to inspire **his** followers."

Comment: Is followers apt to be used to describe employees in a corporate?

Comment: @yathish Well, personally, I wouldn't use the unqualified word *leader* in a corporation. But, if I did, I would not find *follower* at inappropriate.

Comment: What do you mean unqualified? A CEO could rightly be called a leader. But followers sounds odd to refer to the employees. I had team leaders in my mind originally..

Comment: @yathish By *unqualified*, I mean not collocated with another word. Just as you said, there could be a *team leader*. *Team* is qualifying the word *leader*. But aside from generic usage (or in the qualified sense), there is no position called *leader* at a company.

Comment: @yathish Also, in the case of *team leader*, I would not say *team follower* (that could be ambiguous). I would say *team member*.

Answer (score 0):

A leader needs to be both gregarious and exemplary to inspire **those they lead**.

Not one word but it gets the point across without showing unnecessary superiority like "led" and "followers" seems to.

Comment: *A leader needs to be ... gregarious* Not really, history is full of examples of leaders who stood far apart from those they led.